# How to perform a case-insensitive match in MarkLogic 6

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

Hi I have used cts search and XPath query in MarkLogic and also I have used more than one parameter. I need to capture both capital and small character (inside the XML search).

Sample XML

```
<PP uri="/2000_4_174.xml">
  <P name="jur" value="ht"/>
  <P name="sitting" value="17 AUGUST"/>
  <P name="startpage" value="174"/>
</PP>
```

My XQuery

```
let $attr1  := "JUR"
let $attr2  := "startpage"
let $value1 := "ht"
let $value2 := "174"

let $uri := //PP[P[@name=$attr1 and @value=$value1] and   P[@name=$attr2 and @value=$value2]]/@uri
return $uri
```

When $attr1 value is **jur**, the query runs successfully but I want to provide the value either caps or lower case. Please let me know any options.

Note: After changing the collation cts search working both caps and lower case, but the XPath query not working.

Comment: Showing some sample code and input would make clearer what exactly you are after..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To address the XPath part of the problem, you can do a case insensitive match.

```
let $attr1  := "JUR"
let $attr2  := "startpage"
let $value1 := "ht"
let $value2 := "174"

let $uri := //PP[P[fn:matches(@name, $attr1, "i") and @value=$value1] and 
    P[@name=$attr2 and @value=$value2]]/@uri
return $uri
```

I'd expect this to be slightly slower, but it will match regardless of the case.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you understand the use of collations:

https://docs.marklogic.com/6.0/guide/search-dev/encodings_collations

Comment: I have changed the collation (http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1) in particular DB  in word lexicons , I have passed the attribute Name dynamically and value also , Value only worked either caps and small but Attribute name not working can you please find out anything wrong with my side?

Comment: I think you will need to provide more detail for more assistance.  query sample, data sample, settings, etc..

Comment: I have provide sample xml and Xquery for your persual.